# Using Kafka and Schema registry, I encode and decode Avro data but how do I do handle GenericRecord data processing downstream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, telemetry

I am building a telemetry pipeline processing for our project. I have AVRO encoded coming in and with the use of the Schema registry, I am decoding Avro data as GenericRecord based on the SchemaID. I am planning to run Spark jobs for further downstream processing. But, what is the best way to handle the data model in Spark jobs ? All examples point to using result.get("fieldname") but is that the suggested way ?

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using GenericRecord is that, it abstracts out the schema registry related details from the consumer. So, you don't have to fetch the schema id from the payload record, make a GET call to the confluent schema registry to get the avro schema, and then do the deserialization. I don't know of any performance impacts because of this, but would surely love to know if there's any.

On the other hand if you wish to use your own avro bytearray serializer/deserializer, you need to have some knowledge of the structure of the avro payload. E.g. you've to parse the avro payload to validate the magic byte, extract the 4 byte schema Id and the schema, and so on... You might want to implement an in-memory cache of already retrieved schemas, because it's a good idea to reduce the number of http calls to schema registry. More details on this, can be found [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html).